# Website not working when adding .htaccess

Tags: htaccess, apache, centos

I have my website hosted on a CentOS server. When I add the `.htaccess` file it stops working showing "Internal Server Error".

On a side note: when I remove the `.htaccess` file the website works only with www.

I've checked and mod_rewrite is on and shared.

What can be wrong?

```
    //Rewrite to www
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com[nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [r=301,nc]

//Prevent viewing of .htaccess file
<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>

//Prevent directory listings
Options All -Indexes
```

Comment: That means there is a problem with *something* in your .htaccess file.  It isn't clear to me just by looking at it what it is.  It could be a typo.   It could be a module that isn't loaded by Apache.  It could be that Apache is configured not to allow overrides.   Do you have access to the error_log which will have more specific information?   Have you tried putting just one rule into *.htaccess* at at time to see if any of them work on their own?

Answer (score 3):

I haven't checked the syntax on the rules, but my first reaction is that the comments look wrong. Try replacing the two forward slashes with a hash mark and make sure the # is the first character on the line. The rest looks fine, but I'd also remove the [nc] from the first RewriteCond line.

The code to prevent the viewing of .ht* files should also exist in the main apache config file too. It would be more secure to make it a server-wide setting and I would hope that it's the default for the package.

Comment: Good catch.  *.htaccess* files do indeed use `#` comments, and not `//`.

Comment: "remove the [nc] from the first RewriteCond line" - I wouldn't necessarily remove the `[nc]` flags argument altogether, however, a _space_ delimiter is required before it (otherwise the rule simply won't do anything, since the condition will never match). However, the `NC` flag on the following `RewriteRule` is entirely superfluous, and there should probably be an `L` flag here in case any other directives are added in the future.